# Python:absolute value of each element of a matrix inside a loop

Tags: python, numpy, absolute-value

In python (I am new working with python), I have a matrix built inside a loop in the following way:

```
A[:,index_i ,index_j] = B[:,index_i ,index_j] - C[:,index_i ,index_j]
```

Just after that inside the same loop there are some calculations on `A`, but before I need to get `A` with each element positive for those operations, then, writing this will work so each `A[k,index_i,index_j]>=0`?

```
A[:,index_i ,index_j]= abs( B[:,index_i ,index_j] - C[:,index_i ,index_j] )
```

If possible, I want to avoid more loops to have every element positive.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the time to read this post on how to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming these are numpy arrays, the below should work quite well:

```
A[:, i,j] = np.abs(B[:, i, j]- C[:,i, j])
```

Indeed, you can even skip the i, j loop and simply right:

```
A = np.abs(B-C)
```

to get the same outcome in a more pythonic and faster way.

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `abs` function accepts a scalar value. You can use numpy's function

```py
import numpy as np
result = np.abs(...)
```